# Add a shared button across JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, frame, jtabbedpane

Hey everyone I've been using this as my guide and the base for my code that I've been working on:

[Java Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

What I want to do, is add a shared button across all of the panes. I dont want to declare a unique button for each one, but one that is shared. My first thought was to change the frame to boxlayout and just toss a button in after it adds the pane to the frame:

```
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    //Add content to the window.
    //frame.add(new GUI(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(new GUI());

    //setup Find button
    //findButton.setSize(110,55);
    findButton.setText("Find"); 
    findButton.setVisible(true);

    //add button to frame
    frame.add(findButton);
```

However, I get a runtime error: BoxLayout can't be shared. So now I wind up here. While I look into why I'm getting this error, can someone let me know if this is the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Consider placing the JButton in a JPanel that is below or above the JTabbedPane so that it is always visible, and you will only need one button.
- Or if it must be in a component held in the tabs, then each will need its own unique JButton, but they can share the same Action, which is what I recommend you do: Create an inner private class that extends AbstractAction, create an instance of this inner class, pass it into each JButton via either the JButton's constructor or its `setAction(...)` method.
- Your BoxLayout problem is completely unrelated to your original question and should not even be part of this discussion. Yes, a BoxLayout must be used in one container, and that same container should be passed into the BoxLayout. Likely you're adding it to the JFrame, but in reality this adds it to the JFrame's contentPane, and so for this to work, you must pass `frame.getContentPane()` into the BoxLayout's first constructor parameter:

---

```
frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

This is one reason I don't like adding components or setting layouts directly on the top level window since it is nothing but misleading syntactic sugar.

I much prefer:

```
JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

Comment: Thank you, your final option did the trick. The reason to mention the BoxLayout was, because that was MY attempt to fix the problem. It also demostrates the layout I'm trying to achieve physically. I like to always show the route I take as well. This can lead to a better idea as to what I'm trying to do and/or discussion of why it may not be the best approach. Thanks for the 3 options. I'm going with door number 3 :D.

Comment: I'm still a newb to gui's etc and haven't touched java in over a year. Finally, have motivation to come back to it. Thanks for the reminder about the constructor and the getContentPane(), this is something I have overlooked before and really need to commit to memory.

Comment: I used your approach with using a JPanel with a JButton inside it then added the panel to the frame as well. Both visually seem to do the same thing. Which is better? Why?

Comment: @whitewolfpgh: please describe option 1 again?

Comment: option 1: new panel, add button, add to frame

Comment: option 2: add button directly to the frame

Comment: @whitewolfpgh: oh, so you're asking is it better to add the JButton directly to the contentPane vs. adding it to a JPanel that is then added to the contentPane. The answer: whichever works best for you in this situation. My experience has been that when I find myself adding a button to a GUI, I often find myself adding several more buttons, so I often create a JPanel, say buttonPanel, that often uses a `GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0)` (1 row, variable columns, 5 space between,...) or something similar so that I have a nice row of buttons.

Comment: okay good idea thank you! That is a much better long term solution. I just added a few buttons with each of the methods and this looks best:button + JPanel -> contentPane. Looks much nicer with grid layout, fills the gaps.